# Instantiate particular class based on object value

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have classes for each payment mode for e.g. `Cash`, `Cheque`, `Card`. I have to pass object as a   parameter based on object value I have to instantiate a relevant class.

How can I achieve this? Suggest me a better design

```
public interface CollectionInfo {
    //Code Goes here
}

public class Cash implements CollectionInfo {
    //Code goes here
}

public class CollectionFactory {
    public void newInstance(Enum<CollectionMode> collectionMode) {
    }
}

public interface Receipts {
    public Receipt createReceipt(String Amount, /*(Here i need to pass parameter of object either cash ,Cheque or card),*/Date date);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but I am utterly confused by what you are asking. Maybe you should include code and/or pseudo-code of what is being attempted.

Comment: *"Regards
Vijay"*  Don't include sigs. in questions, they are noise.  Also, there is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass an enumeration (Cash/Cheque/Card) into a factory ?

e.g.

```
Payment p = PaymentFactory.newInstance(PaymentMode.Cash);
```

and within that method you would do:

```
switch(mode) {
   case PaymentMode.Cash:
      return new CashPayment();

   // ...
}
```

where `CashPayment`, `ChequePayment` etc. are subclasses of `Payment`.

Comment: Or if you want to be hyper-dynamic, some naming convention and `Class.forName`. But the factory is probably the better way...

Comment: Yes. I didn't want to complicate matters too much

Comment: @BrianAgnew public interface CollectionInfo{
 
 //Code Goes here
}

public class Cash implements CollectionInfo
{
 //Code goes here
}

public class CollectionFactory {

 public void newInstance(Enum<CollectionMode> collectionMode) {

 }

}


public interface Receipts{
 
 public Receipt createReceipt(String Amount, /*(Here i need to pass parameter of object either cash ,Cheque or card),*/Date date);
}

Comment: @VijayM: To improve your question by adding details, use the "edit" link under the question (and the code formatting tools in the resulting editor).

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the factory pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern